# How is the matrix size declared in this formula?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I want to understand how the size matrix is declared within this formula:

```
=arrayformula(if(row(A:A)=1,"Unique ID",if(len(A:A)=0,iferror(1/0),A:A*100000)))
```

Comment: It would greatly improve readability to use the title to briefly explain the problem, and then include the code and question in the body.

Answer (score 0):

cut it to for better understanding:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Unique ID"; IF(LEN(A2:A), A2:A*100000, )})
```